# how to run scrapy from virtual env on mac os x

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, virtualenv

I am trying to run scrapy on mac os x.  The problem is that the dependencies are giving me a hard time in my default pyton installation. I would instead like to run scrapy from my virtual env.

If I just type "`scrapy`" in my terminal it is using the default python installation and not the one installed in my virtual env.

Even if I activate virtual env with `source venv/bin/activate`  It will use the default installation if I don't instruct scrapy to use virutal env.

How can I force scrapy to use virtual env?

Comment: what happens when you install scrapy (`pip install scrapy`) when you are inside the virtualenv?

Comment: type `which python` and feed the result into `ls -l <path>`.  That's the version of python that it will use.

Comment: @zengr it installs it and gives me the error No module named lxml.html

Comment: you probably have to install the prerequisites which are not pure python, such as lxml, using a package manager like `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had lots of issues getting Scapy and its dependencies properly installed on my Mac, finally I found the Homebrew Python GitHub page https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python it contains lots of helpful/useful brew formula including one for Scapy that worked like a charm for me. Simply clone the repo and run these commands:

```
brew tap Homebrew/python
brew install scapy
```

I also had an issue with my pcapy which was solved by another formula in the repo for pypcap, so same procedure.

```
brew install pypcap
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable the global site packages in your virtualenv. You can recreate the venv with `--system-site-packages` or use `toggleglobalsitepackages` if you have `virtualenvwrapper`.

Then you can either create a custom `scrapy` runner with this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute()
```

or modify your default scrapy command (see `which scrapy`), replacing the line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```